# The local html site redirect to online site

Tags: javascript, html

I have a local HTML website and when I try to open it as local site it's going to an online website, I search everywhere but I can't find the problem, my guess is this Javascript code

```
var packageX=
'|||||||||||o|||function|e||i||c|||m|t||document|on||p|var|apScrollTop|s||a|v|getElementById|option|window|l|navigator||g|01|d|r||userAgent||w|||popup||||n|match|css|return|for|||te|u|go|ny|style|mo|className|ma||change|this|nots|er|ac|os|co|new|wa|||ll||ai||iris|ar|al|it|h|do|ri|nd|ck|pt|oo|se||mc|ta|bi|test|fixResizeThings|_|opera|ip|k|g1|pl|ts|ca|up|od|Date|in|cover|bodyKeeper|val|mobile|left|'
+String.fromCharCode(0x61,0x72,0x73,0x61,0x63,0x69,0x61)+
'|button|location|ir|margin|active|blur|notsMobile|removeClass|getElementsByClassName|1e3|px|getTime|daysInMonth|UpdateTime|parseInt|addClass|display|android|height|xo|palm|cr|rc|oa|mmef|02|mmp|o8|mi|me|netfront|ui|firefox|ob|m1|kgt|keji|klon|kpt|kwc|kddi|jigs|pocket|ipaq|ja|jbro|jemu|kyo|plucker|de|lynx|m3ga|ixi|m50|libw|re|le|no|xi|lg|phone|midp|p800|owg1|blackberry|pan|pdxg|oran|wv|op|elaine|compal|ti|blazer|pg|phil|prox|rt|psio|meego|qa|bada|po|pire|ay|uc|pn|fennec|hiptop|n10|maemo|lge|n20|n30|mywa|inno|zz|mt|p1|mwbp|n50|kindle|wt|wg|nok|nzph|o2im|wf|tf|n7|hone|iemobile|ne|bb|hu|cldc|770s|cmd|4thp|mp|chtm|cell|c55|capi|ccwa|cdm|craw|da|xiino|xda|dc|devi|1207|6310|3gso|6590|ng|dbte|bw|802s|as|ch|us|attw|au|aptu|yw|amoi|rn|an|ex|di|avan|abac|az|br|bumb|ko|bl|be|nq|lb|rd|dica|dmob|browser|hs|treo|ht|symbian|link|hp|hcit|hd|hei|hi|tp|av|idea|psp|ig01|ikom|ibro|iac|aw|tc|series|i230|haie|un|em|wap|l2|ul|vodafone|avantgo|qc|ds|el|ce|windows|ic|k0|gene|gf|gr|ad|g560|fly|esl8|ez|ze|fetc|im1k|sl|wonu|x700|wmlb|nw|wi|nc|yas|your|vendor|mobcheck1|substr|zte|zeto|whit|webc|veri|vi|v750|v400|utst|rg|vk|vx|w3c|vulc|voda|vm40|mobcheck2|detectmob|closePopup|click|beOnLoading|position|speed|containerAA|stop|body|ready|fadeOut|loaderClass|showLoginPopup|visibility|visibilityTrigger|userpnav|offsetHeight|none|popupcontent|07|width|767|enabled|custom|toLowerCase|host|52px|si|popupcontrols|sp|sgh|ft|so|sy|mb|gt|00|t6|ms|t5|b3|shar|sa|ge|sie|s55|sk|sm|zo|id|mm|ve|t2|sdk|tim|r380|sc|tel|sh|b|qtek|tx|m5|m3|tdg|to|rim9|tcl|va|ro|raks|lk|r600|doLogin|apstEnabled|apstScrolledTo|apstDestroy|www|apstBeforeScrollTo|apstDisabled|apstToggle|pointer|https|alert|homeNav|setInterval|resize|apstCssClassesUpdated|apstInit|onInit|apstPositionUpdated|overflow|keyCode|1600|remove|keyup|scrollSpeed|toggle|close|load|jQuery|onclick|loginbtn|footer|scroll|offset|top|image|trigger|checked|auto|fade|ipad|playbook|silk|visibilityFadeSpeed|is|typeof|mouse|getPosition|minFont|NotSupportedForAnims|maxFont|getDate|offsetLeft|scrollLeft|clientTop|offsetParent|scrollTop|offsetTop|clientLeft|Tipped|create|iPad|iPod|iPhone|webOS|Android|BlackBerry|behavior|mobileAndTabletcheck|inline|mobilecheck|Phone|Windows|events|x|now|undefined|offsetWidth|y|flowtype|AGHeader|null|accessnav|innerWidth|5em|15px|innerHTML|marginLeft|fontRatio|block|marginTop|lgnPopupT|2100|out|removeAttribute|show|toFixed|2014|tooltip|tpd';
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};
    if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e)
    {return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)
{if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}
('14 365(){58 39.46.56(/502/17)||39.46.56(/501/17)||39.46.56(/500/17)||39.46.56(/498/17)||39.46.56(/499/17)||39.46.56(/503/17)||39.46.56(/509 508/17)?!0:!1}14 346(){37.507=14(){29 11=!1;58 14(15){(/(139|235\\43+|201).+119|317|203\\/|186|195|193|192|209|210|233|106(232|113)|86|223|213 |212|183|148|119.+154|152|105 22(155|115)17|142( 76)?|182|28(174|177)\\/|170|164|301|308(4|6)0|291|289|112\\.(287|292)|316|313|322 321|251|250/17.102(15)||/254|255|257|256|240|50[1-6]17|238|261|33 79|275|75(74|96|31\\-)|84(279|270)|88(299|111|77)|269|271(272|65|268)|267|87(263|64)|262(62|264)|265|266(273|\\-22|44 |31 )|274|281(94|82|282)|101(283|284)|280(75|276)|277(15|34)48|278|260\\-(55|63)|244\\/|245|246|247\\-|243|242|237|239\\-|77(241|93)|248|249(89|82|258)|259|252\\-31|253|285|286|91(19|28)11|319(12|\\-43)|320(49|84)|312(314|315)|74(323|324)|331|332([4-7]0|76|79|333)|334|330(\\-|104)|108 63|329|325|326\\-5|41\\-67|64(\\.48|113)|327(328|311)|310|294|295\\-(22|28|23)|296\\-|297(95|100)|293( 17|106)|288\\-19|290(19(\\-| |104|33|41|28|31|23)|298)|236(306|307)|17\\-(20|64|69)|309|305( |\\-|\\/)|304|300|302|303|335|217|165|86|166(23|34)33|167|168|163|162|158|157( |\\/)|159|160 |161\\-|169(19|107)|178(179|180)|181( 41|\\/(107|38|63)|50|54|\\-[33-48])|176|172|156\\-48|173|175\\/|69(62|153|141)|99(42|21|111)|22\\-143|151(144|92)|150(149|145|110)|146|67(42|147|101|171|91|23(\\-| |11|34)|218)|219(50|220|34 )|221|216|211[0-2]|214[2-3]|215(0|2)|222(0|2|5)|231(0(0|1)|10)|234((19|22)\\-|26|230|229|225|224)|226(6|17)|227|228|191(194|190)|189|185|184|187(33|43|23)|188|196(13|\\-([1-8]|19))|197|205|109(206|207)|208\\-2|204(94|199|97)|198|200|95\\-41|202\\-33|318(384|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|17\\-)|425|420|437|435|431|434(416|413)|410\\/|407(408|69|415|403|65|433)|421(42|90\\-|96|28\\-)|418\\/|97(19(\\-|0|1)|47|99|93|92)|395\\-|406|409(\\-|22)|411\\-0|336(45|414)|412(88|87|405|89|404)|397(396|65)|394(42|90\\-|34\\-|34 )|398(42|399)|417(18|50)|402(401|10|18)|100(400|436)|432\\-|429\\-|422(17|22)|419\\-|23\\-67|430(109|423)|110(70|22\\-|428|427)|426\\-9|112(\\.424|108|392)|356|355|354|352|353(357|62)|358(40|5[0-3]|\\-34)|363|362|361|359(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|360(\\-| )|351|350|341(41 |342|340)|339|337|338|343\\-|344|349|348\\-/17.102(15.347(0,4)))&&(11=!0)}(39.46||39.345||37.105),11}}14 364(){37.505=14(){29 11=!1;58 14(15){(/(139|235\\43+|201).+119|317|203\\/|186|195|193|192|209|210|233|106(232|113)|86|223|213 |212|183|148|119.+154|152|105 22(155|115)17|142( 76)?|182|28(174|177)\\/|170|164|301|308(4|6)0|291|289|112\\.(287|292)|316|313|322 321|251|250|139|477|478|479/17.102(15)||/254|255|257|256|240|50[1-6]17|238|261|33 79|275|75(74|96|31\\-)|84(279|270)|88(299|111|77)|269|271(272|65|268)|267|87(263|64)|262(62|264)|265|266(273|\\-22|44 |31 )|274|281(94|82|282)|101(283|284)|280(75|276)|277(15|34)48|278|260\\-(55|63)|244\\/|245|246|247\\-|243|242|237|239\\-|77(241|93)|248|249(89|82|258)|259|252\\-31|253|285|286|91(19|28)11|319(12|\\-43)|320(49|84)|312(314|315)|74(323|324)|331|332([4-7]0|76|79|333)|334|330(\\-|104)|108 63|329|325|326\\-5|41\\-67|64(\\.48|113)|327(328|311)|310|294|295\\-(22|28|23)|296\\-|297(95|100)|293( 17|106)|288\\-19|290(19(\\-| |104|33|41|28|31|23)|298)|236(306|307)|17\\-(20|64|69)|309|305( |\\-|\\/)|304|300|302|303|335|217|165|86|166(23|34)33|167|168|163|162|158|157( |\\/)|159|160 |161\\-|169(19|107)|178(179|180)|181( 41|\\/(107|38|63)|50|54|\\-[33-48])|176|172|156\\-48|173|175\\/|69(62|153|141)|99(42|21|111)|22\\-143|151(144|92)|150(149|145|110)|146|67(42|147|101|171|91|23(\\-| |11|34)|218)|219(50|220|34 )|221|216|211[0-2]|214[2-3]|215(0|2)|222(0|2|5)|231(0(0|1)|10)|234((19|22)\\-|26|230|229|225|224)|226(6|17)|227|228|191(194|190)|189|185|184|187(33|43|23)|188|196(13|\\-([1-8]|19))|197|205|109(206|207)|208\\-2|204(94|199|97)|198|200|95\\-41|202\\-33|318(384|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|17\\-)|425|420|437|435|431|434(416|413)|410\\/|407(408|69|415|403|65|433)|421(42|90\\-|96|28\\-)|418\\/|97(19(\\-|0|1)|47|99|93|92)|395\\-|406|409(\\-|22)|411\\-0|336(45|414)|412(88|87|405|89|404)|397(396|65)|394(42|90\\-|34\\-|34 )|398(42|399)|417(18|50)|402(401|10|18)|100(400|436)|432\\-|429\\-|422(17|22)|419\\-|23\\-67|430(109|423)|110(70|22\\-|428|427)|426\\-9|112(\\.424|108|392)|356|355|354|352|353(357|62)|358(40|5[0-3]|\\-34)|363|362|361|359(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|360(\\-| )|351|350|341(41 |342|340)|339|337|338|343\\-|344|349|348\\-/17.102(15.347(0,4)))&&(11=!0)}(39.46||39.345||37.105),11}}14 134(11,15){58 78 114(15,11,0).488()}14 486(){58 346()||364()||365()?!0:!1}14 484(11){59(29 15=0,23=0;11;)15+=11.489-11.490+11.495,23+=11.494-11.493+11.491,11=11.492;58{511:15,515:23}}14 366(){$(".393").57("138","382"),25.35("117").68="116 127-530",$(".383").375(529,14(){51.68="",25.35("117").68="116"})}14 377(){29 11=78 114,15=11.133();37.528=15+131,$(".393").57("138","526"),25.130("383")[0].531("66"),51.68="532",25.35("117").68="116 127-115",$(".536-535").57("138","382"),103()}14 135(){59(29 11=78 114(534,2,1,0,0,0,0),15=11.133(),23=78 114,55=23.133(),17=55-15,33=(17/131).533(),19=33,31=0,28=0,44=1,38=1,22=0;19>=60;)31++,19-=60;59(;31>=60;)28++,31-=60;59(;28>=24;)44++,28-=24;59(;44>=134(38,22);)44-=134(38,22),38++;59(;38>=12;)22++,38-=12;0>=38&&(38=1);29 43=25.35("512");10>44&&(44="0"+44),10>19&&(19="0"+19),10>28&&(28="0"+28),10>31&&(31="0"+31),"513"!=482 43&&518!=43&&(43.523=22+" سال و "+38+" ماه و "+44+" روز و "+28+" ساعت و "+31+" دقيقه و "+19+" ثانيه")}14 103(){$(37).385()<=386?($("#380").57("125-120","-522"),$(".73").137("128"),$(".73").129("73")):($("#380").57("125-120","0.521"),$(".128").137("73"),$(".73").129("128")),$("#519").57("125-120","");29 11=37.520,15=.24*11;25.35("517").66.140=15+"132";29 23=25.35("51").514,55=25.35("51").381;25.35("51").66.524=-(23/2)+"132",25.35("51").66.527=-(55/2)+"132",55=25.130("468")[0].381,$(37).385()>386&&(25.130("126")[0].66.140="391",25.35("449").66.140="391")}14 438(){448("در حال حاضر امکان ورود وجود ندارد.\\55")}"121.124"!=123.390.389()&&"442.121.124"!=123.390.389()&&(37.123="447://121.124");29 368=!1;$(25).374(14(){135(),450(135,131),$.30({454:14(11){}}),$.30().26("453",14(11){}),$.30().26("445",14(11,15){}),$.30().26("452",14(11){}),$.30().26("455",14(11){}),$.30().26("439",14(11){}),$.30().26("444",14(11){}),$.30().26("443",14(11,15){}),$.30().26("440",14(11,15){}),$.30().26("441",14(11,15){}),103(),$(37).451(14(){103()})}),$("#36-387").26("71",14(){29 11=$(72).481(":474");$.30("36","387",11)}),$("#36-378-473").26("71",14(){29 11=$(72).118();"388-14"==11?$.30("36","379",14(11){29 15=$("#472-59-388-14").470();58 11>15.471}):$.30("36","379",136(11))}),$("#36-378-476-370").26("71",14(){29 11=136($(72).118());$.30("36","480",11)}),$("#36-469-370").26("71",14(){29 11=136($(72).118());$.30("36","461",11)}),$("#36-369").26("71",14(){29 11=$(72).118();$.30("36","369",11)}),$(25).460(14(11){27==11.457&&"116 127-115"==25.35("117").68&&0==368&&366()}),$(".462").26("367",14(){$(".371").372().137("126")}),$(".463").26("367",14(){$(".371").372().129("126")});29 51=25.35("51"),122=25.35("467");122&&(122.466=14(){377()}),465(14(11){29 15=11("#376");11(37).464(14(){11("#376").375(458,14(){15.459(),11("373").57({456:"475","446-510":""})})})}),$("373").516({525:60,485:10,487:16}),$(25).374(14(){496.497(".506","",{504:"483"})});'
    ,10,537,packageX.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Comment: It happened with me once, and I got to know there was a meta tag which was redirecting it. Please check the meta tags in the code.

Comment: Meta tags are ok, I checked that

Comment: it redirects to a online website

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: its this  `<noscript>&lt;meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=jsnoten.htm"&gt; </noscript>` but when i remove this and open it again it happens again, nothing changed

Comment: No, this link will be activated only when Javascipt is turned off (`noscript` tag). Dos the site go live straight away or only when you click on a link?

Comment: its go live straight

Comment: Do you open it from a local server that has a .htaccess file? Also, your code in the question is packed, hard to see what it does (but seems to have an impact on `location`), can you unpack it somehow?

Comment: No, There is no .access file or htaccess

Comment: may be the .htaccess file in invisible or hidden mode. Please check the folder and show all hidden file enable to see the hidden file from view.

Comment: I checked now, there is no hidden files in any of folders or main folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition was right, the script does it.

to unpack it, I just replaced `return p` by `console.log(p)` and ran it in a developper tool console of a blank page.

The part concerning `location` is this one:

```
"arsacia.ir"!=location.host.toLowerCase()&&"www.arsacia.ir"!=location.host.toLowerCase()&&(window.location="https://arsacia.ir");
```

I can't provide any robust solution without knowing where the packed code comes from. You have somehow to remove this from the unpacked code and pack it again. I personnally won't go through all the scrambled code to try to remove it (even if it is theorically possible to do it by removing the `location|` -and maybe others- from first string and their associated params in the second string).

**EDIT:** as a workaround, you can still replace `location` by a fake variable:

- Be cautious about this, it will work because currently `location` is only used in the code shown above, but that may not always be the case
- The var name should not be used elsewhere (I chose `fakeLocation`)
- You have to define the var before, as an object with `host` property as a string if you don't want the code to throw an error

Which gives:

```
var fakeLocation = { host: '' };
var packageX=
'|||||||||||o|||function|e||i||c|||m|t||document|on||p|var|apScrollTop|s||a|v|getElementById|option|window|l|navigator||g|01|d|r||userAgent||w|||popup||||n|match|css|return|for|||te|u|go|ny|style|mo|className|ma||change|this|nots|er|ac|os|co|new|wa|||ll||ai||iris|ar|al|it|h|do|ri|nd|ck|pt|oo|se||mc|ta|bi|test|fixResizeThings|_|opera|ip|k|g1|pl|ts|ca|up|od|Date|in|cover|bodyKeeper|val|mobile|left|'
+String.fromCharCode(0x61,0x72,0x73,0x61,0x63,0x69,0x61)+
'|button|fakeLocation|ir|margin|active|blur|notsMobile|removeClass|getElementsByClassName|1e3|px|getTime|daysInMonth|UpdateTime|parseInt|addClass|display|android|height|xo|palm|cr|rc|oa|mmef|02|mmp|o8|mi|me|netfront|ui|firefox|ob|m1|kgt|keji|klon|kpt|kwc|kddi|jigs|pocket|ipaq|ja|jbro|jemu|kyo|plucker|de|lynx|m3ga|ixi|m50|libw|re|le|no|xi|lg|phone|midp|p800|owg1|blackberry|pan|pdxg|oran|wv|op|elaine|compal|ti|blazer|pg|phil|prox|rt|psio|meego|qa|bada|po|pire|ay|uc|pn|fennec|hiptop|n10|maemo|lge|n20|n30|mywa|inno|zz|mt|p1|mwbp|n50|kindle|wt|wg|nok|nzph|o2im|wf|tf|n7|hone|iemobile|ne|bb|hu|cldc|770s|cmd|4thp|mp|chtm|cell|c55|capi|ccwa|cdm|craw|da|xiino|xda|dc|devi|1207|6310|3gso|6590|ng|dbte|bw|802s|as|ch|us|attw|au|aptu|yw|amoi|rn|an|ex|di|avan|abac|az|br|bumb|ko|bl|be|nq|lb|rd|dica|dmob|browser|hs|treo|ht|symbian|link|hp|hcit|hd|hei|hi|tp|av|idea|psp|ig01|ikom|ibro|iac|aw|tc|series|i230|haie|un|em|wap|l2|ul|vodafone|avantgo|qc|ds|el|ce|windows|ic|k0|gene|gf|gr|ad|g560|fly|esl8|ez|ze|fetc|im1k|sl|wonu|x700|wmlb|nw|wi|nc|yas|your|vendor|mobcheck1|substr|zte|zeto|whit|webc|veri|vi|v750|v400|utst|rg|vk|vx|w3c|vulc|voda|vm40|mobcheck2|detectmob|closePopup|click|beOnLoading|position|speed|containerAA|stop|body|ready|fadeOut|loaderClass|showLoginPopup|visibility|visibilityTrigger|userpnav|offsetHeight|none|popupcontent|07|width|767|enabled|custom|toLowerCase|host|52px|si|popupcontrols|sp|sgh|ft|so|sy|mb|gt|00|t6|ms|t5|b3|shar|sa|ge|sie|s55|sk|sm|zo|id|mm|ve|t2|sdk|tim|r380|sc|tel|sh|b|qtek|tx|m5|m3|tdg|to|rim9|tcl|va|ro|raks|lk|r600|doLogin|apstEnabled|apstScrolledTo|apstDestroy|www|apstBeforeScrollTo|apstDisabled|apstToggle|pointer|https|alert|homeNav|setInterval|resize|apstCssClassesUpdated|apstInit|onInit|apstPositionUpdated|overflow|keyCode|1600|remove|keyup|scrollSpeed|toggle|close|load|jQuery|onclick|loginbtn|footer|scroll|offset|top|image|trigger|checked|auto|fade|ipad|playbook|silk|visibilityFadeSpeed|is|typeof|mouse|getPosition|minFont|NotSupportedForAnims|maxFont|getDate|offsetLeft|scrollLeft|clientTop|offsetParent|scrollTop|offsetTop|clientLeft|Tipped|create|iPad|iPod|iPhone|webOS|Android|BlackBerry|behavior|mobileAndTabletcheck|inline|mobilecheck|Phone|Windows|events|x|now|undefined|offsetWidth|y|flowtype|AGHeader|null|accessnav|innerWidth|5em|15px|innerHTML|marginLeft|fontRatio|block|marginTop|lgnPopupT|2100|out|removeAttribute|show|toFixed|2014|tooltip|tpd';
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};
    if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e)
    {return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)
{if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}
('14 365(){58 39.46.56(/502/17)||39.46.56(/501/17)||39.46.56(/500/17)||39.46.56(/498/17)||39.46.56(/499/17)||39.46.56(/503/17)||39.46.56(/509 508/17)?!0:!1}14 346(){37.507=14(){29 11=!1;58 14(15){(/(139|235\\43+|201).+119|317|203\\/|186|195|193|192|209|210|233|106(232|113)|86|223|213 |212|183|148|119.+154|152|105 22(155|115)17|142( 76)?|182|28(174|177)\\/|170|164|301|308(4|6)0|291|289|112\\.(287|292)|316|313|322 321|251|250/17.102(15)||/254|255|257|256|240|50[1-6]17|238|261|33 79|275|75(74|96|31\\-)|84(279|270)|88(299|111|77)|269|271(272|65|268)|267|87(263|64)|262(62|264)|265|266(273|\\-22|44 |31 )|274|281(94|82|282)|101(283|284)|280(75|276)|277(15|34)48|278|260\\-(55|63)|244\\/|245|246|247\\-|243|242|237|239\\-|77(241|93)|248|249(89|82|258)|259|252\\-31|253|285|286|91(19|28)11|319(12|\\-43)|320(49|84)|312(314|315)|74(323|324)|331|332([4-7]0|76|79|333)|334|330(\\-|104)|108 63|329|325|326\\-5|41\\-67|64(\\.48|113)|327(328|311)|310|294|295\\-(22|28|23)|296\\-|297(95|100)|293( 17|106)|288\\-19|290(19(\\-| |104|33|41|28|31|23)|298)|236(306|307)|17\\-(20|64|69)|309|305( |\\-|\\/)|304|300|302|303|335|217|165|86|166(23|34)33|167|168|163|162|158|157( |\\/)|159|160 |161\\-|169(19|107)|178(179|180)|181( 41|\\/(107|38|63)|50|54|\\-[33-48])|176|172|156\\-48|173|175\\/|69(62|153|141)|99(42|21|111)|22\\-143|151(144|92)|150(149|145|110)|146|67(42|147|101|171|91|23(\\-| |11|34)|218)|219(50|220|34 )|221|216|211[0-2]|214[2-3]|215(0|2)|222(0|2|5)|231(0(0|1)|10)|234((19|22)\\-|26|230|229|225|224)|226(6|17)|227|228|191(194|190)|189|185|184|187(33|43|23)|188|196(13|\\-([1-8]|19))|197|205|109(206|207)|208\\-2|204(94|199|97)|198|200|95\\-41|202\\-33|318(384|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|17\\-)|425|420|437|435|431|434(416|413)|410\\/|407(408|69|415|403|65|433)|421(42|90\\-|96|28\\-)|418\\/|97(19(\\-|0|1)|47|99|93|92)|395\\-|406|409(\\-|22)|411\\-0|336(45|414)|412(88|87|405|89|404)|397(396|65)|394(42|90\\-|34\\-|34 )|398(42|399)|417(18|50)|402(401|10|18)|100(400|436)|432\\-|429\\-|422(17|22)|419\\-|23\\-67|430(109|423)|110(70|22\\-|428|427)|426\\-9|112(\\.424|108|392)|356|355|354|352|353(357|62)|358(40|5[0-3]|\\-34)|363|362|361|359(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|360(\\-| )|351|350|341(41 |342|340)|339|337|338|343\\-|344|349|348\\-/17.102(15.347(0,4)))&&(11=!0)}(39.46||39.345||37.105),11}}14 364(){37.505=14(){29 11=!1;58 14(15){(/(139|235\\43+|201).+119|317|203\\/|186|195|193|192|209|210|233|106(232|113)|86|223|213 |212|183|148|119.+154|152|105 22(155|115)17|142( 76)?|182|28(174|177)\\/|170|164|301|308(4|6)0|291|289|112\\.(287|292)|316|313|322 321|251|250|139|477|478|479/17.102(15)||/254|255|257|256|240|50[1-6]17|238|261|33 79|275|75(74|96|31\\-)|84(279|270)|88(299|111|77)|269|271(272|65|268)|267|87(263|64)|262(62|264)|265|266(273|\\-22|44 |31 )|274|281(94|82|282)|101(283|284)|280(75|276)|277(15|34)48|278|260\\-(55|63)|244\\/|245|246|247\\-|243|242|237|239\\-|77(241|93)|248|249(89|82|258)|259|252\\-31|253|285|286|91(19|28)11|319(12|\\-43)|320(49|84)|312(314|315)|74(323|324)|331|332([4-7]0|76|79|333)|334|330(\\-|104)|108 63|329|325|326\\-5|41\\-67|64(\\.48|113)|327(328|311)|310|294|295\\-(22|28|23)|296\\-|297(95|100)|293( 17|106)|288\\-19|290(19(\\-| |104|33|41|28|31|23)|298)|236(306|307)|17\\-(20|64|69)|309|305( |\\-|\\/)|304|300|302|303|335|217|165|86|166(23|34)33|167|168|163|162|158|157( |\\/)|159|160 |161\\-|169(19|107)|178(179|180)|181( 41|\\/(107|38|63)|50|54|\\-[33-48])|176|172|156\\-48|173|175\\/|69(62|153|141)|99(42|21|111)|22\\-143|151(144|92)|150(149|145|110)|146|67(42|147|101|171|91|23(\\-| |11|34)|218)|219(50|220|34 )|221|216|211[0-2]|214[2-3]|215(0|2)|222(0|2|5)|231(0(0|1)|10)|234((19|22)\\-|26|230|229|225|224)|226(6|17)|227|228|191(194|190)|189|185|184|187(33|43|23)|188|196(13|\\-([1-8]|19))|197|205|109(206|207)|208\\-2|204(94|199|97)|198|200|95\\-41|202\\-33|318(384|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|17\\-)|425|420|437|435|431|434(416|413)|410\\/|407(408|69|415|403|65|433)|421(42|90\\-|96|28\\-)|418\\/|97(19(\\-|0|1)|47|99|93|92)|395\\-|406|409(\\-|22)|411\\-0|336(45|414)|412(88|87|405|89|404)|397(396|65)|394(42|90\\-|34\\-|34 )|398(42|399)|417(18|50)|402(401|10|18)|100(400|436)|432\\-|429\\-|422(17|22)|419\\-|23\\-67|430(109|423)|110(70|22\\-|428|427)|426\\-9|112(\\.424|108|392)|356|355|354|352|353(357|62)|358(40|5[0-3]|\\-34)|363|362|361|359(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|360(\\-| )|351|350|341(41 |342|340)|339|337|338|343\\-|344|349|348\\-/17.102(15.347(0,4)))&&(11=!0)}(39.46||39.345||37.105),11}}14 134(11,15){58 78 114(15,11,0).488()}14 486(){58 346()||364()||365()?!0:!1}14 484(11){59(29 15=0,23=0;11;)15+=11.489-11.490+11.495,23+=11.494-11.493+11.491,11=11.492;58{511:15,515:23}}14 366(){$(".393").57("138","382"),25.35("117").68="116 127-530",$(".383").375(529,14(){51.68="",25.35("117").68="116"})}14 377(){29 11=78 114,15=11.133();37.528=15+131,$(".393").57("138","526"),25.130("383")[0].531("66"),51.68="532",25.35("117").68="116 127-115",$(".536-535").57("138","382"),103()}14 135(){59(29 11=78 114(534,2,1,0,0,0,0),15=11.133(),23=78 114,55=23.133(),17=55-15,33=(17/131).533(),19=33,31=0,28=0,44=1,38=1,22=0;19>=60;)31++,19-=60;59(;31>=60;)28++,31-=60;59(;28>=24;)44++,28-=24;59(;44>=134(38,22);)44-=134(38,22),38++;59(;38>=12;)22++,38-=12;0>=38&&(38=1);29 43=25.35("512");10>44&&(44="0"+44),10>19&&(19="0"+19),10>28&&(28="0"+28),10>31&&(31="0"+31),"513"!=482 43&&518!=43&&(43.523=22+" سال و "+38+" ماه و "+44+" روز و "+28+" ساعت و "+31+" دقيقه و "+19+" ثانيه")}14 103(){$(37).385()<=386?($("#380").57("125-120","-522"),$(".73").137("128"),$(".73").129("73")):($("#380").57("125-120","0.521"),$(".128").137("73"),$(".73").129("128")),$("#519").57("125-120","");29 11=37.520,15=.24*11;25.35("517").66.140=15+"132";29 23=25.35("51").514,55=25.35("51").381;25.35("51").66.524=-(23/2)+"132",25.35("51").66.527=-(55/2)+"132",55=25.130("468")[0].381,$(37).385()>386&&(25.130("126")[0].66.140="391",25.35("449").66.140="391")}14 438(){448("در حال حاضر امکان ورود وجود ندارد.\\55")}"121.124"!=123.390.389()&&"442.121.124"!=123.390.389()&&(37.123="447://121.124");29 368=!1;$(25).374(14(){135(),450(135,131),$.30({454:14(11){}}),$.30().26("453",14(11){}),$.30().26("445",14(11,15){}),$.30().26("452",14(11){}),$.30().26("455",14(11){}),$.30().26("439",14(11){}),$.30().26("444",14(11){}),$.30().26("443",14(11,15){}),$.30().26("440",14(11,15){}),$.30().26("441",14(11,15){}),103(),$(37).451(14(){103()})}),$("#36-387").26("71",14(){29 11=$(72).481(":474");$.30("36","387",11)}),$("#36-378-473").26("71",14(){29 11=$(72).118();"388-14"==11?$.30("36","379",14(11){29 15=$("#472-59-388-14").470();58 11>15.471}):$.30("36","379",136(11))}),$("#36-378-476-370").26("71",14(){29 11=136($(72).118());$.30("36","480",11)}),$("#36-469-370").26("71",14(){29 11=136($(72).118());$.30("36","461",11)}),$("#36-369").26("71",14(){29 11=$(72).118();$.30("36","369",11)}),$(25).460(14(11){27==11.457&&"116 127-115"==25.35("117").68&&0==368&&366()}),$(".462").26("367",14(){$(".371").372().137("126")}),$(".463").26("367",14(){$(".371").372().129("126")});29 51=25.35("51"),122=25.35("467");122&&(122.466=14(){377()}),465(14(11){29 15=11("#376");11(37).464(14(){11("#376").375(458,14(){15.459(),11("373").57({456:"475","446-510":""})})})}),$("373").516({525:60,485:10,487:16}),$(25).374(14(){496.497(".506","",{504:"483"})});'
    ,10,537,packageX.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Comment: Edited the answer with a workaround solution that can make it temporary

Answer (score 0):

As you told, I searched online javascript unpacker and edit the code, and pack it again and put it back and it worked perfectly fine